# How to create a dynamic form using WizardView (Django 1.4)?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

The full problem statement involves multiple steps, however, at the heart of it is this simple scenario:

Lets say I have two forms

```
from django import forms

class Form1(forms.Form):
    char_field1=forms.CharField(label='field 1')
    char_field2=forms.CharField(label='field 2')
    char_field3=forms.CharField(label='field 3')

class Form2(forms.Form):
    choice_field = forms.ChoiceField()
```

Now using `django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView` or its subclass I would like to populate the choice_field with the options filled by the user in `char_field1` - `char_field3`.

I tried overriding the `get_form` and populating the choice_field when Form2 was to be returned. It did show the options in the form rendered, but the form didn't validate upon submission.

My gut feel says that it should be possible, the 'how' is what I am not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never... I have run into this scenario myself recently and had to override the form's (for the second step) init method and pass an initial keyword from the WizardView to the form. From there I could conditionally set the choices for a form field.

My own implementation-

views.py

```
class QuoteWizard(SessionWizardView):
    form_list = [QQFormProductLine, QQProduct, QQProductFluidProperties]
    ...
    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        #pass variables to forms from here
        initial = self.initial_dict.get(step, {})
        if int(step) > 0:
            self.temperature_units, self.measurement_format = self.get_measurement_units()
            initial.update({'measurement_format': self.measurement_format})
        return initial
```

forms.py

```
class QQProduct(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QQProduct, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        units = None 

        if 'initial'in kwargs:
            initial = kwargs.pop('initial')
            if 'measurement_format' in initial:
                units = initial.pop('measurement_format')

        flow_choices = []
        if units == 'imperial':
            flow_units = qq_models.FlowRateUnits()
            flow_units = flow_units.imperial()
        elif units == 'metric':
            flow_units = qq_models.FlowRateUnits()
            flow_units = flow_units.metric()

        for i in flow_units:
            flow_choices.append((i, qq_models.FlowRateUnits.get(i)))
        if len(flow_choices) > 0:
            self.fields['flow_rate_format'].widget.choices = flow_choices
```

In summary, get_form_initial is a WizardView method that passes initial keywords to the form for a step. In my self.get_measurement_units() method, I call self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0') and, depending on user input in the first step, change the choices displayed in a choicefield in the second step's form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import CookieWizardView

class ChoiceWizardView(CookieWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        pass

    def get_form(self, step=None, data=None, files=None):
        form = super(ChoiceWizardView, self).get_form(step, data, files)
        if 'choice_field' in form.fields:
            form1_cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0')
            if form1_cleaned_data:
                form.fields['choice_field'].choices = [item for item in form1_cleaned_data.items()]
        return form
```

urls.py:

```
from app.forms import Form1, Form2
from app.views import ChoiceWizardView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^my_wizard/$', ChoiceWizardView.as_view([Form1, Form2])),
)
```

It will work. But maybe you chose wrong application architecture?

Comment: yes I have already tried it. The choices show up in the form alright, but validation fails stating the chosen value is not a valid choice.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I haven't tested for this. My bad. Now it seems like working example. Changed condition, when field fills with data.